# how to add new line on an created text file ?(php)

Tags: php

i am working on a php script. it is as follows:

```
<?
$a='a b c d e';
$b=explode(" ",$a);
foreach ($b as $c) {

$filename = 'test.txt';
$fp = fopen($filename, "a+");
$write = fputs($fp, $c."/n");
fclose($fp);

}
?>
```

the output (test.txt) comes as this:

```
a/nb/nc/nd/ne/n
```

But I want to get the text file like this:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

can any body tell me how to do this?

Comment: /n and \n are not the same thing....

Comment: You put the slash for the newline character backwards. It should be: "\n".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape sequences are indicated with a `\` not `/` - so you need to use "\n" to put a newline into your string (and file)

Answer (score 4):

on line 8 you can add \n\r

This will make it cross platform from Windows/MAC/LINUX/UNIX.

eg.
$write = fputs($fp, $c."\r\n");